# Heroku Postgress TAPS To Amazon RDS MySQL Migration Encoding

Tags: postgresql, heroku, encoding, amazon-web-services

Im in the middle of trying to migrate fro Heroku shared Postgres to Amazon RDS MySQL instance, and iv followed all the steps listed here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

The migration went through fine, all the data was transferred except iv now noticed that any characters that arent the usual english charset are now question marks,  like  "?????"

I have a lot of users of my app from China, Thailand etc and all of their entered data is just questions marks,  as though it has no idea how to encode it.

I know Heroku replaces the database.yml, so theres no use me showing you that,  and I cant see any options to configure encoding on RDS.

All I did was the usual heroku db:pull mysql2://user:pass@isntance/db

Does anyone know how im able to migrate this data without screwing up the characters for these other languages?

Cheers

Comment: Googling "amazon rds mysql utf8" seems to give plenty of solutions

Comment: Thanks, iv just run through this whole example and set the character set to UTF8, re-run the import but im still seeing question marks everywhere .. http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/howto-configure-an-amazon-rds-instance-to-use-utf-8-925.html

Comment: Actually, it seems the import resets the tables to Latin instead of UTF8, because now their all set to Latin after re-running TAPS.

Comment: Please check the spelling of your title: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out for anyone else who reads this.

You need to follow the instructions about setting your character set here: http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/howto-configure-an-amazon-rds-instance-to-use-utf-8-925.html

But what I was missing is that I needed to drop the database completely and recreate it.  The new charset applied to all new tables then.

Comment: include answers in your reply please, the original link is broken